# Python: eliminating stack traces into library code?

Tags: python

When I get a runtime exception from the standard library, it's almost always a problem in my code and not in the library code.  Is there a way to truncate the exception stack trace so that it doesn't show the guts of the library package?

For example, I would like to get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./lmd3-mkhead.py", line 71, in <module>
    main()
  File "./lmd3-mkhead.py", line 66, in main
    create()
  File "./lmd3-mkhead.py", line 41, in create
    headver1[depotFile]=rev
TypeError: Data values must be of type string or None.
```

and not this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./lmd3-mkhead.py", line 71, in <module>
    main()
  File "./lmd3-mkhead.py", line 66, in main
    create()
  File "./lmd3-mkhead.py", line 41, in create
    headver1[depotFile]=rev
  File "/usr/anim/modsquad/oses/fc11/lib/python2.6/bsddb/__init__.py", line 276, in __setitem__
    _DeadlockWrap(wrapF)  # self.db[key] = value
  File "/usr/anim/modsquad/oses/fc11/lib/python2.6/bsddb/dbutils.py", line 68, in DeadlockWrap
    return function(*_args, **_kwargs)
  File "/usr/anim/modsquad/oses/fc11/lib/python2.6/bsddb/__init__.py", line 275, in wrapF
    self.db[key] = value
TypeError: Data values must be of type string or None.
```

**update:** added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615414/python-eliminating-stack-traces-into-library-code/2616262#2616262) with the code, thanks to the pointer from Alex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the pointer from Alex, here's teh codez:

```
def trimmedexceptions(type, value, tb, pylibdir=None, lev=None):
    """trim system packages from the exception printout"""
    if pylibdir is None:
        import traceback, distutils.sysconfig
        pylibdir = distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib(1,1)
        nlev = trimmedexceptions(type, value, tb, pylibdir, 0)
        traceback.print_exception(type, value, tb, nlev)
    else:
        fn = tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename
        if tb.tb_next is None or fn.startswith(pylibdir):
            return lev
        else:
            return trimmedexceptions(type, value, tb.tb_next, pylibdir, lev+1)

import sys
sys.excepthook=trimmedexceptions

# --- test code ---

def f1(): f2()
def f2(): f3()
def f3():
    import xmlrpclib
    proxy = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://nosuchserver')
    proxy.f()

f1()
```

Which yields this stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tsttraceback.py", line 47, in <module>
    f1()
  File "./tsttraceback.py", line 40, in f1
    def f1(): f2()
  File "./tsttraceback.py", line 41, in f2
    def f2(): f3()
  File "./tsttraceback.py", line 45, in f3
    proxy.f()
gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 12):

The [traceback](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html?highlight=traceback#module-traceback) module in Python's standard library lets you emit error tracebacks in a way that accords to your liking, while an exception is propagating.  You can use this power either in the `except` leg of a `try`/`except` statement, or in a function you've installed as [sys.excepthook](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html?highlight=sys#sys.excepthook), which gets called if and when an exception propagates all the way; quoting the docs:

> In an interactive session this happens
>   just before control is returned to the
>   prompt; in a Python program this
>   happens just before the program exits.
>   The handling of such top-level
>   exceptions can be customized by
>   assigning another three-argument
>   function to sys.excepthook.

Here's a simple, artificial example:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import traceback
>>> def f(n):
...   if n<=0: raise ZeroDivisionError
...   f(n-1)
... 
>>> def excepthook(type, value, tb):
...   traceback.print_exception(type, value, tb, 3)
... 
>>> sys.excepthook = excepthook
>>> f(8)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in f
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in f
ZeroDivisionError
```

as you see, without needing a `try`/`except`, you can easily limit the traceback to (for example) the first three levels -- even though we know by design that there were 9 nested levels when the exception was raised.

You want something more sophisticated than a simple limit on levels, so you'll need to call [traceback.format_exception](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html?highlight=traceback#traceback.format_exception), which gives you a list of lines rather than printing it, then "prune" from that list the lines that are about modules you never want to see in your tracebacks, and finally emit the remaining lines (typically to `sys.stderr`, but, whatever!-).

Comment: pure distilled wisdom, mixed with a dash of style... thanks Alex!

Answer (score 1):

The [Traceback library](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html) is probably what you want. Here's one example that might help:

```
import traceback

try:
    your_main()
except:
    lines = traceback.format_exc()
    print lines[:lines.find('File "/usr')]
```

(This obviously won't work if there's an exception outside the library, and might not exactly fit your needs, but it's one way of using the traceback library)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Mark and Alex's responses, I was able to get what I wanted. I have improved the code. Now it removes libraries not only from the end, but from anywhere. This is quite useful for stacktrace from large applications, for example in server applications where control can be passed from user code to library code and back again.

```py
import traceback
from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib

def trim_exceptions(type, value, tb):
    """trim system packages from the exception printout"""
    lib_dir = get_python_lib(True, False).lower()
    current_tb = tb
    prev_node = None

    while current_tb:
        fn = current_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename
        if fn.lower().startswith(lib_dir):
            if prev_node:
                prev_node.tb_next = current_tb.tb_next
            else:
                tb = current_tb.tb_next
        else:
            prev_node = current_tb
        current_tb = current_tb.tb_next

    traceback.print_exception(type, value, tb)
```

This function can also be used as a hook `sys.excepthook=trim_exceptions` and explicitly called in your code:

```py
try:
    return await call_next(request)
except Exception as exc:
    trim_exceptions(type(exc), exc, exc.__traceback__)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put an unqualified try...except at the top of your code (ie: in your "main") or set `sys.excepthook`. You can then format the stack trace however you'd like.