# How do I mangle the exception stack in python to remove inner calls?

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following:

```
def foo():
    bar()

def bar():
    baz()

def baz():
    raise ValueError("hello")

foo()
```

unsurprisingly, the trace is

```
$ python x.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 10, in <module>
    foo()
  File "x.py", line 2, in foo
    bar()
  File "x.py", line 5, in bar
    baz()
  File "x.py", line 8, in baz
    raise ValueError("hello")
ValueError: hello
```

Now suppose I want the traceback to look like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 10, in <module>
    foo()
ValueError: hello
```

That is, I want to be able to remove the topmost two entries in the stack trace, and I want to do it within `baz()`, that is, at the raising of the exception, either by mangling the stack, or by crafting the raised exception in a special way.

Is it possible?

**Edit**: one option would be to raise inside baz and catch immediately, then re-raise with a trimmed traceback, but I don't know how to do it.

**Edit 2**:

what I need is this, in pseudocode

```
def baz():
    raise ValueError, "hello", <traceback built from current frame stack, except the last two>
```

Comment: appears as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615414/python-eliminating-stack-traces-into-library-code?rq=1 but in practice isn't. the control I want is different

Comment: It's not that different what you want, really.

Comment: @Martijn it is. I can't override excepthook, and I want control on baz, where the exception is generated

Comment: You want only the display to be trimmed, not the traceback itself. Right?

Comment: @keith: also the traceback. nothing must know of the existence of bar and baz.

Comment: ok, I think I've finally understood what you want: to raise the exception in baz but to make it look like it actually came from foo. You can't do that from bar or baz. Why not catch in foo and re-raise there (after all, foo _must_ know about bar at least)?

Comment: @isedev: I can't because bar and baz are actually decorators, and foo knows nothing about them

Comment: I think you need to restate your question more accurately. Your example is misleading... As it stands, foo() calls bar(), so it knows about it. Can you show some code which better represents your problem?

Comment: @isedev: you really don't want to see it. it's like monty python's funniest joke in the world. If you read it, you die.

Comment: The `raise` example you post doesn't work on Python, because the traceback is not built in advance.  It is built lazily when the exception propagates.  But it looks easy enough to add to `foo()` code like: `try: bar(); except Exception, e: raise e`, which would re-raise any exception from within itself rather than from wherever it really came from.