# Remove calls from the traceback

Tags: python, python-3.x, traceback

I have a small class in `geometry.py`:

```py
class Pyramid():
    def __init__(self, sign, name):
        if len(sign.split(".")) != 2:
            raise ValueError("pyramid must have 1 apex and 1 base")
        ...
```

The constructor ensures that the pyramid has 1 apex and 1 base.

```py
S = geometry.pyramid("S.ABCD", "S")
```

When something wrong with the if statement, such as:

```py
S = geometry.pyramid("S.A.BCD", "S")
```

It will error and print a traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Main\WORK STATION\PYTHON\GEOMETRY\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    S = geometry.pyramid("S.A.BCD", "S")
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\Main\WORK STATION\PYTHON\GEOMETRY\geometry.py", line 46, in __init__
    raise ValueError("pyramid must have 1 apex and 1 base")
ValueError: pyramid must have 1 apex and 1 base
```

The traceback shows calls in 2 files, but i only want to keep the error description (last line) and the first call, and hide the most recent one. I would prefer if I only need to edit `geometry.py`, instead of `main.py` or both.

Expected traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Main\WORK STATION\PYTHON\GEOMETRY\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    S = geometry.pyramid("S.A.BCD", "S")
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: pyramid must have 1 apex and 1 base
```

I tried to use `sys.tracebacklimit`, but it was not really helpful.

Comment: That question about syntax highlighting should be asked on a site where Microsoft Word is on-topic; you could try [su]. Pretty sure there are already questions, if you search for "syntax highlighting", though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Raise an exception from a higher level, a la warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34175111/raise-an-exception-from-a-higher-level-a-la-warnings)

Comment: Ah, that's not a very good duplicate target… I can't actually find a good duplicate target, so I propose making this the new canonical for this topic.

Comment: Wait, do you care about the _actual exception_, or just how it's output? If you just care about the output, [Python: eliminating stack traces into library code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2615414/5223757) is a duplicate.

Comment: those things are too complicated for me to understand, and it's better if someone can help me with the specific code and explanation

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a specific code help service: we answer general questions, and try to make them as general as possible so as many people can use them as possible. If you don't understand those questions, I've probably misunderstood this one: [what's the reason you want to do this?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/308065)

Comment: uhh ok, I'm sorry then  :((（；´д｀）ゞ

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about! If you can't find your answer, that _is_ the kind of problem that Stack Overflow addresses: just, we address it by writing better _general_ materials, and not by doing personal tuition. I'd appreciate your help in figuring out which part you don't understand, because it's unlikely you're the first (or last) person who doesn't get this.

Comment: @D.L It's technically a series of variables: a point, and a polygon, which together form a pyramid. I'm not even sure whether there _is_ an English name for that.

Comment: @wizzwizz4,  it is not defined as this from the code that is shown in the question. But from what you have described is called a `pyramid` or `tetrahedron` in mathematics.

Comment: @D.L Because JACOBnotpro has produced a [mcve] for us. The variable `sign` holds the _string describing_ the pyramid, not a pyramid itself, so "pyramid" wouldn't be a good name (and neither would `tetrahedron`, because the base is not necessarily triangular: in this example, it's a quadrilateral).

Comment: just add if tetrahedron have 4 vertices :))) But name object is not the main idea :ll

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure _why_ you want this. Just to see if you can? Do you want to make error messages clearer for people using your `geometry.py` module? Are you trying to present a better error to the user of an application? (I edited the question a bit based on your now-deleted answer, but it's still a guess.)